# Securing oauth bearer token against attacks such as XSS, CSRF in javascript apps

Tags: security, cookies, oauth, xss, csrf

I am a bit unclear about how to secure (or protect) bearer tokens when using pure JavaScript applications.

I know when user request token to the server it can come with a validity of 14 days or 24 hours. but once the user has token there is no neat (assured) way of securing this from XSS or CSRF attacks (am I missing something?).

Now lets say user is logged into the web application and the browser has this token which is valid for 14 days. If the user is accessing another web application which is trying to do XSS (or CSRF) then the token is exposed to the third party application and this application can make calls to the my application using this token (?)

I have tried to search online but nothing concrete (or something which is easy to understand) coming up for pure js apps and how to protect the token. Or there isn't a good way to do it in js atm. and you just hope (and pray) that the attack will not take place within the validity of token (i.e. 14 days :|)?

Any thoughts or inputs are welcome to this.

Thanks

Edit: It prob. goes without saying but we are assuming the use of SSL certificate.

Comment: I think you need to understand what a [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) and an [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) attack is before you start trying to protect your application from them.

Answer (score -1):

So, a very quick summary. CSRF occurs because a request to a HTTP end point automatically includes cookies (as it should) plus required headers as described by the server and doesn't require a user to physically do something. They simply visit a web page with the CSRF vector on.

CSRF is generally said to be possible if there is no use of a unique "secret" passed firstly to the client and back to the server to verify that the user indeed intended to make the call. Generally speaking, web browsers are shaping the main ways to protect against CSRF for any type of application. [CSRF on OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF))

As you've pointed out, you use a bearer token (sent as a HTTP header) - but you are still protected because requests need to originate from the same origin by default. IF the server allows calls from all origins which is returned in the HTTP headers (which tells your user's web browser if it is allowed) then on their heads be it [Same origin policy here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php?title=Same-Origin_Policy&action=edit&redlink=1).

As for XSS, as long as your cookies at the very least have the "HTTP" flag they are invisible to javascript code on any page the user visits anyway. Plus strictly speaking XSS vectors including the theft of cookies for your site would need to be performed on your site generally speaking. Off the top of my head I can't think of anyway to steal them unless a user is physically on your site. If you set the "Secure" flag this is even better as it forces "Server" only too and ensures the cookie will only be sent when a TLS/SSL connection has been established. [XSS on OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS))

Here is a screenshot of cookies listed with the Secure and HTTP flags:
[image: A mixture of cookies - some cookies need to be accessed by javascript though like google trackers!]

As an extra, make sure you always enforce TLS connections as otherwise they could become victim to a MITM (Man in the middle) attack on a public WIFI network that forces a protocol downgrade to a weak version of SSL that is susceptible to POODLE or non at all. Please read up on HSTS as it will most definitely reinforce everything I have mentioned and really help to prevent the token from being stolen [HSTS OWASP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) and [HSTS info wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)