# JWT with Bearer Token protect from CSRF and XSS whilst using AJAX

Tags: ajax, jwt, xss, csrf

I have a webapp that has a javascript page that makes ajax calls up to the webservices. The authorization scheme used for the site is JWT with bearer tokens being used in the authorization header.

However, I now realize that I am vulnerable to XSS, because the token is being stored in a cookie, and the javascript needs access to this in order to set the bearer token in it's requests. Because of this, httponly is set to false, thus meaning my token can be stolen.

So, what I would like to know is whether there is a way to protect against both CSRF and XSS whilst using ajax requests and JWTs?

Comment: Sadly, this question is not answered. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24362593/1816580) goes into the same direction. Perhaps everybody's using bearer tokens and storing the token in a location accessible to JS, because they think that if there is XSS then it is game over, because the XSS payload has access to all client and server data in the name of the logged in user. But the issue is that exfiltrating the bearer token enables the attacker to issue commands in an interactive fashion.

Comment: A possible solution might be to make the bearer token lifetime extremely small, such as several minutes and create an API which is http-only cookie authenticated to be a refresh endpoint for the bearer token.